# Scrapy text extract is not correct

Tags: scrapy

I have a Problem.

I want to get a text (the Price) on a site. Every other things like title/name works, but not the price.

`price = product.css('.offerList-item-priceWrapper .priceRange::text')[0].extract().replace('ab','').replace('*','').replace('\xc2','').replace('\xa0','').replace('€','').strip()`

Thats the price call...

Thats the html site

```
<div class="offerList-item-priceWrapper">
        <div class="offerList-item-pricePrefix">
                        <span></span>
                        <span class="offerList-item-pricePrefixCount">62 Angebote</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="priceRange">
                        <span class="priceRange-from">
                            <span class="price-from">
                                ab</span>
                            <span class="price-currencySymbol price-currencySymbol--before">€</span>
                            30,82<span class="price-currencySymbol price-currencySymbol--after">&nbsp;€</span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="priceRange-to">
                            <span class="price-currencySymbol price-currencySymbol--before">€</span>
                            126,61<span class="price-currencySymbol price-currencySymbol--after">&nbsp;€</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

You cannot that there are really much whitespaces...
If i print my price, i get only whitespaces back.

I put a screenshot here, there you can see the console of chrome [image: please check here]

I think there so much whitespaces, that i dont get the 30,82 in that example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to simplify it quite a bit for you.

```
pricerange-from = product.css('div.priceRange span.priceRange-from::text').getall()[2].strip()
pricerange-to = product.css('div.priceRange span.priceRange-to::text').getall()[1].strip()
```

Practice using selectors a little more. Hope this answer shows you where you could've went wrong.